# Scroll to top Button is not showing in my React project

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, scrolltop

The scroll to the top button is not showing after the scroll reaches 300 pixels. The scroll event is not triggering. I think the problem is maybe with react router Dom v6, because, when I apply the same code in other projects without a React router, the code works. When I manually change the state to true, the button shows, but has no functionality. I'm using "react": "^18.2.0", "react-dom": "^18.2.0", "react-router": "^6.3.0", "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0". This is my first React project, so I'm new to this. I would really appreciate it if someone could please help me with this. This is my code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BiArrowFromBottom } from "react-icons/bi";
import "./scrollToTop.scss";

const ScrollToTop = () => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  const toggleVisibility = () => {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 300) {
      setIsVisible(true);
    } else {
      setIsVisible(false);
    }
  };

  const scrollToTop = () => {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      behavior: "smooth",
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", toggleVisibility);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", toggleVisibility);
    };

  }, []);

  return (
      <div className="top-to-btm">
        {isVisible && (
          <BiArrowFromBottom
            onClick={scrollToTop}
            className="icon-position icon-style"
          />
        )}
      </div>
  );
};

export default ScrollToTop;



import ScrollToTop from "./components/backtotop/scrollToTop";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
        <ScrollToTop />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;


.top-to-btm {
    position: relative;
  }
  .icon-position{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 35px;
    z-index: 20;
  }
  .icon-style{
    background-color: #725034;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    animation: movebtn 3s ease-in-out infinite;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  }
  .icon-style:hover{
    animation: none;
    background: #fff;
    color: #725034;
    border: 2px solid  #725034;
  }
  @keyframes movebtn {
    0%{
      transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    25%{
      transform: translateY(20px);
    }
    50%{
      transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    75%{
      transform: translateY(-20px);
    }
    100%{
      transform: translateY(0px);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue you describe. Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-to-top-button-is-not-showing-in-my-react-project-h44cun) demo. Typically when I see "scrolling to top" issues it's caused by nesting a scrollable container somewhere and it's ***not*** the window that's scrolling to an offset to update any state. Please edit the post to include a more complete [mcve]. Feel free to also fork my linked sandbox and add more of your code to reproduce the issue that we can then inspect live.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance Drew. In my original code, I had a typo. I have written 'Scroll' instead of 'scroll'.